# What is Verb "scale" meaning in Engineering?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The current (electricity) produced by a fuel cell **scales** with the size of the reaction area
where the reactants, the electrode, and the electrolyte meet. In other words, doubling a fuel
cell’s area approximately doubles the amount of current produced.

I think there's proper meaning in dictionary. What's this meaning here?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+scale&oq=define+scale&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2319j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Etymology 3, verb sense 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the difference of the meaning of the verb "scale" between engineering and everyday life.

When you buy some water, the money you spend **scales** with the amount of water. Assume a bottle of water sells for $1, 10 bottles cost you $10, 55 bottles cost you $55.

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to find this use of "scale" (intransitive) in a dictionary. I did find a similar meaning in Wiktionary
[Wiktionary "scale" (verb, intransitive)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scale)

3: (intransitive, computing) To tolerate significant increases in throughput or other potentially limiting factors. for example,
    *That architecture won't scale to real-world environments.*

The use you quoted seems to extend that use, from computing or industrial processes, to electrical engineering. It's quite understandable, but "scales with" seems to mean no more than "is proportional to".

Answer (score 1):

I can't really find a good definition of the engineering sense in a dictionary but if we start from this sense of scale:

> a ratio of size in a map, model, drawing, or plan.
>   "a one-fifth scale model of a seven-storey building"

So I can buy a 1:100 scale model ship or a 1:50 000 scale map. If I buy a scale model I expect it to accurate, apart from the size.

In engineering and science, as your original text says, it means "proportional to" or "approximately (linearly) proportional to". For example, if I say: "The heat loss in a fusion reactor scales as the surface area of the plasma but the heat production scales as the volume" that tells you that large fusion reactors are better.